# Using JPA metamodel for @OneToMany mappedBy

Tags: jpa-2.0, metamodel

Could someone explain what is wrong with this and is there a workaround?

```
private static final String parentField = AbstractType_.parent.getName();
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = parentField)
private List<AbstractType> children = new ArrayList<AbstractType>();
```

In eclipse, this shows and error on the @OneToMany line:

> While this would be fine:
>   The value for annotation attribute OneToMany.mappedBy must be a constant expression.

Also the Maven build fails because of this.

Then again, this will work fine.

```
private static final String test = "";
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = test)
private List<AbstractType> children = new ArrayList<AbstractType>();
```

UPDATE:
What is happening here, that I wish to get the field name via metamodel, but one can not refer to it at 'mappedBy' attribute.